# How do I change unicode u'\xb0C' from SQL to string °C in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, character-encoding, python-unicode

I SELECT data from SQL into temp_data dictionary but there is a unit value like `"u't_unit': u'\xb0C'"` which I can't convert to string °C in python.

**Python Code:**

```py
temp_data = [{u'thresh_id': 508, u'app_guid': u'7D83E6F8D879BE17C95D14879159973A', 
u'override': 1, u'thresh_guid': u'BB8F3E8184783E0416EEA7D19D9C9FBC', 
u'app_id': 1102, u'edit_user': 1, u'h_range': Decimal('100.000'), 
u't_type': 1, u't_value': Decimal('0.000'), u'l_range': Decimal('0.000'), 
u't_unit': u'\xb0C', u'edit_date': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 30, 4, 24, 44), 
u'name': u'Sensor Temperature High Major'}]
```

I used the following code to get my required values:

**Python Code:**

```py
b = []  
for i in temp_data:  
    a = ('Dynamic', i['name'], i['thresh_id'], i['t_unit'], i['t_value'], i['l_range'], i['h_range'])  
    b.append(a)  
    b = [tuple(str(item) for item in t) for t in b]  
final_data = (",".join(map(str,b)))
```

The **error message** received:
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xb0' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

**Expected result:**

```
('Dynamic', 'Sensor Temperature High Major', '508', '°C', '0.000', '0.000', '100.000')
```

I tried to use `'u'\xb0C'.encode('utf8')'` to convert it, but it is not working.

How could I get the result as expected?
Thank you very much.

Comment: You don't need to encode anything as your own question proves - SO uses UTF8 like almost all sites and stores text in `nvarchar` (Unicode) database fields. It doesn't perform any special encoding. What is the encoding of the database field? You may not have to do *anything* to store and retrieve `°C`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When processing `unicode` data in Python 2, it's important to use the [unicode](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#unicode) and [str](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#str) types consistently.  Ideally, use only `unicode` inside your application, and convert to and from `str` only when receiving input, or generating output, only when necessary.

The values in temp_data are either `unicode` or non-string types, so we want to process them as `unicode` objects rather than `str`.

```
>>> b = []
>>> for i in temp_data:
...     a = ('Dynamic', i['name'], i['thresh_id'], i['t_unit'], i['t_value'], i['l_range'], i['h_range'])
...     b.append(a)
...     # Cast items to unicode, not str
...     b = [tuple(unicode(item) for item in t) for t in b]
... 
>>> # Now all our items are unicode strings
>>> b
[(u'Dynamic', u'Sensor Temperature High Major', u'508', u'\xb0C', u'0.000', u'0.000', u'100.000')]
>>> # Join each tuple with unicode strings as the join value.
>>> final_data = (u','.join(u','.join(x) for x in b))  
>>> # Now the data prints correctly.
>>> print final_data
Dynamic,Sensor Temperature High Major,508,°C,0.000,0.000,100.000
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. It is quite nice.
However, I have multiple data that need to put into string and INSERT back to other SQL server.

There is still an error when INSERT to SQL:
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xb0' in position 34970: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: The error on INSERT could have a couple of causes - the db is not configured to accept unicode as input, or the db connection is not configured to handle unicode.  You could have a look at some of the answers returned by googling "UnicodeEncodeError sql site:stackoverflow.com" or ask a new question if none of them work for you.  The question ought to include: the database being used, the driver package, any ORM being used, the connection string/url  and sample code and data that reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you use `python 2.*`.That's because you're printing the tuple. For example if you access the specific value you'll see that it is printed normally. Try this:

```
b = []
for i in temp_data:
    a = ('Dynamic', i['name'], i['thresh_id'], i['t_unit'], i['t_value'], i['l_range'], i['h_range'])
    print(i['t_unit'])  # prints °C
    print(a[3])  # prints °C
```

Comment: There's no reason to encode/decode anything if the fields are stored in a UTF8 field.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you're right. Just forgot to delete while testing.

Comment: Yeah, I found out the issue was caused by code:
` b = [tuple(str(item) for item in t) for t in b] ` which I used to remove Decimal() in temp_data.
Do you know how to remove Decimal() and encode u'\xb0C' together?
Thank you.